# Django multi user handling

Tags: python, django, ajax, session

I’m writing an app which a user can calculate some values and get a graph from them.

I thought what would happen when multiple users fire a request for calculating?
I can store variables in session but I’m not sure what will happen when multiple users fire a method at the same time.

Eg.

```py
def calc(self,x,y):
test = []
test.append(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the session storage used. But in short, this should *just work* because session storage is per-session (which usually also translates to per user). So all your users data should be separate when using sessions.

However, keep in mind that it is possible for you to receive a stale value (from the same user) from the session -- again, depending on the backend used. For example this can happen with the [cookies backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions). -- If the same user requests the endpoint too quickly (e.g., sends two requests before receiving any response and updating cookies from the subsequent responses) then you will end up sending two responses each with different data and only 1 will "win" ultimately. But you won't mix up data *between* users. To avoid *this* problem, don't use the cookie backend (or other backend without freshness guarantees).